# When to use the abbreviations f and ff in scientific literature?

Tags: writing-style, formatting

As discussed in [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/12703/28895), the abbreviations *f* and *ff* can be used to refer to following page numbers. For instance, pages 45-46 can be written as 45f. This is quite common in German law, but I wonder if it is commonly accepted for scientific publications? I work in the engineering field, but I would be interested in a more general answer.

Further questions that come to mind:

- Apart from page numbers, can these abbreviations also be used for line numbers and paragraphs (e.g. lines 10ff, paragraphs 3f? This would be useful as I am currently preparing a review of a paper and need to refer to specific parts of the manuscript.
- Are there cases in which I should prefer specific notations, such as lines 10-23 instead of 10ff?

Comment: What are you trying to do with these abbreviations, and in what field? I've not seem them used in STEM publications, but I could imagine if appearing in something more textually focused, like a literary critique.

Comment: I have never come across these..

Comment: @jakebeal literature guy here. I wouldn't use them as described in the linked question. For me, *f./ff.* are direct equivalents to *p./pp.*, but used for manuscripts and incunables that, instead of being numbered *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...*, are numbered *1r, 1v, 2r, 2v, 3r,  ...* I would probably not recognize it initially to mean the following pages (I'm used to *ss.* for that although I don't know anyone who uses it)

Comment: @jakebeal Engineering - I updated the question.

Comment: I have seen *f* and *ff*, but not in scientific writing.  And never for paragraphs or anything but pages.

Comment: @guifa Sounds like you could give a nice clear answer here --- can you please expand your comment into an answer?

Comment: @jakebeal I could if you think it would a good answer, but the question is for the sciences and I'm in the humanities, that's why I left it as a comment

Comment: @guifa Personally, I would like to see multiple answers for the individual fields. Not sure if this is in line with the SE etiquette.

Comment: Using f and ff is not an accepted style for APS journals (American Physical Society), having just looked through their style manual.

Comment: I don't think I have ever seen this in another language than German (where it is common in every field where you would want to point to a sufficiently long bit of text.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working in STEM fields, I have never seen this form of citations. Instead, on those rare occasions where citations talk about specific locations in a text, people use explicit page and/or line numbers.

I thus suspect that if you used this form of reference in an engineering publication, it will be confusing to your reviewers and readers, and you will be asked to change them.

Comment: Chiming in from biological sciences, specifically neuroscience. Also never seen this and would not recommend.